# Visual Studio 2017 nuget packages exclamation marks even packages restoring completes fine

Tags: angular, nuget, visual-studio-2017, yo

I dont what I am doing wrong but this is so annoying.

Just installed the latest Visual Studio 2017.

I have created a aspnetcore-angular 2  project with using yo aspnetcore-spa template

```
 yo aspnetcore-spa
```

Now I want to simply open the project in Visual Studio 2017 RC.

I would never think that this would be that complicated.

here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/yeoman)  that I have followed.

But now when I open the project in VS 2017 RC I cannot build the project.

I can see that even the nuget packages are referenced they show exclamation marks on them. See the screenshot attached.

[image]
[image]
I tried evething, Update-Package, dotnet restore, etc. But no success.

No idea whats going on with the project.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check the NuGet resources setting?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. The packages restored once i ran VS2017 as an administrator. Hope this Helps.

Comment: Amazing. It seems that it is sufficient to only do this once, start VS and load the project, to clear up the exclamation mark. After that you can open VS without "Run as administrator". @akd, please mark this response as the solution (with 1584 reputation points you should know this by now ;-)

Comment: @Christoph - it doesn't fix the issue for a majority of us.  I answered above which is what I suspect happened for the answer of this inadvertently.